# Just out of curiosity, I would like to try Cobol, what is the easiest free cobol to install on Windows

Tags: cobol

I found this one:
http://tiny-cobol.sourceforge.net/download.php

Not sure to undestand how to install it on Windows. Any other ?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960252/how-to-learn-cobol among others

Comment: @Neil Butterworth my question is not as general. I don't want to know how to learn in general, I want specific name of a free package.

Comment: I work in Banking Industry, I meet a lot of Cobol Guys everyday, so I wanna speak with them less stupidly ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MicroFocus COBOL](http://www.microfocus.com/Resources/Communities/Academic/shop/description.asp?productid=56) looks like you just download the installer (link at bottom of the page) and run it.  This one runs with the .Net framework and claims to let you use Visual Studio 2005 Express if you have it.

Based on this [list of COBOL compilers](http://www.thefreecountry.com/compilers/cobol.shtml), the confusing part about most of them is they compile to C code.  You also would need a C compiler installed (e.g., MinGW) on your computer to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Rebol Tutorial;

Check out OpenCOBOL.  I'm embedding REBOL/3 inside this nifty compiler.  The freshly open sourced libr3.so will allow REBOL scripting from COBOL.  It's going to be fun (and powerful).

http://sourceforge.net/projects/open-cobol/

See the FAQ for installation help, http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/#how-do-i-install-opencobol

and Gary Cutler, the author of the OpenCOBOL Programmer's Guide, has also posted binaries for Windows.  http://sourceforge.net/projects/cobol/files/open-cobol/

As a bonus, a COBOL lexicon highlighter has just been accepted into Pygments, so COBOL code listings on SourceForge will soon support color.  Onward and upwards.